# Getting multiple queries from parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, coronasdk

I am using the following code to get a single entry from parse.com in my corona sdk app. Is there a way to get two entries at the same time, say x1=55.317269 and x1=55.21354. I need the corresponding values for both entries rather than one.

```
local params = {x1=55.317269}
params.headers = headers
params.body = json.encode ( params )
network.request( "https://api.parse.com/1/functions/getFeatured","POST",getData,params)
```

The following is my cloud function.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getFeatured", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("testClass");
  query.equalTo("x1", request.params.x1);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      var sum = 0;
       sum = results[1].get("y1");
       response.success(sum);
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("movie lookup failed");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Try [query.containedIn](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#containedIn)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getFeatured", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("testClass");
  query.containedIn("x1", ARRAY_OF_VALUES_TO_BE_MATCHED);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      // Modify/Create Proper Response Here
      respones.success(results);
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("movie lookup failed");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry Vintesh, guess my question was not clear. I dont want to add specific value to cloud code. I want something like this:           local params = {x1 = 55.317351, 55.317292}                               which gives two values in Corona and gets two corresponding value from parse, all to be handles inside the app.

Comment: I could simply call this local twice params = {x1=var1} but I wonder I can just call once and get both values.

Comment: I still can't get you but try this way - request parameters as - {x1:[55.31,55.317292]} then i know you will get your 2 values.

Comment: Lua give error for using this format. "[" causes problem.

Comment: Check [HERE](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-constraints) for how to use **containedIn** in _queries_